# Drawing a bar graph using UITableViewCell -- cells variably partially filled with color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, drawing

I am trying to implement a table with rows that are partially filled with color. Essentially, I want the functionality to fill my `UITableViewCell`'s background color up to a certain percentage.

Below is an image  of the type of `UITableViewCells` that I want to create. In the image you can see that the first row is fully filled, the second is row is at around 75%, the third row is at around 20%, and so on...

[image: desired effect]

I have made some modifications in this method to no success:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

What have I tried? I attempted adding a subview to each cell's content view.  The subview would be one background color while the actual cell would be a clear color.  Here is a code snippet from my attempt to create cells that are 75% filled:

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
int fillWidth = (75/100) * cell.frame.size.width;

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, fillWidth, cell.frame.size.height);
UIView * view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
[cell.contentView addSubview:view];

//...

return cell;
```

Unfortunately, this did not seem to make any changes in the way the cells were being rendered.

How can I achieve the partially colored effect (shown in the image above)  for each table row?

Comment: Do you set the 'progress' manually (programmatically), or would like to show it as a `UIProgressBar` ?

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/21842/how-to-make-a-gesture-driven-to-do-list-app-part-13

Comment: Also, try using `float`s, and not `int`s for such divisions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your are dividing 2 integers and expecting a double, basically the answer to that is 0. try using 75.0/100.0

Another thing I forgot to mention, the type of variable the cgrect expects is a CGFloat, you are using an int, so you have to fix that too

```
CGFloat fillWidth = (75.0/100.0) * cell.frame.size.width;
```

Comment: In addition, you will either need to remove the added subview (`[cell.contentView addSubview:view];`) in the cell's `prepareForReuse` method or add a view in the cell in storyboard and set the width of that view. Otherwise each time the cell is reused (i.e., when the table is scrolled), it will just another subview.

Comment: Thanks! this seems to have fixed my problem. Now I just have a problem seeing the cell separators but I'll try it out.

Answer (score 1):

the best way i can think of is subclass your UITableViewCell and add UIProgressView and label like

```
@interface UIProgressCell : UITableViewCell {
    UILabel *cellItemName;
    UIProgressView *cellItemProgress;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *cellItemName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIProgressView *cellItemProgress;
```

Do customisation of progress bar like background color and other